# Passing a list as varargs Scala

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, variadic-functions

How can I pass a `List[Any]` of `List[Any]`'s as parameters to `List.concat`? My code is:

```
List.concat((a filter (x => x.getClass == a.getClass)): _*)
```

Where `a` is a `List[Any]` and `(a filter (x => x.getClass == a.getClass))` should become a list of lists. The error I get is `type mismatch; found List[Any] required: Seq[Traversable[Any]]`.

Is there any to pass the elements of a list of parameters, or convert a list to a sequence? Thank you.

Comment: works for me: https://codebrew.io/ftamas/hEqIc1C_QxOcssz2364JsQ

Comment: If I have a list `a = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5))`, how would I make that `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`?

Comment: `List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5)).flatten` produces `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: Also, if a is a `List[Any]` and you apply a filter to it the result is, again, a `List[Any]` and this is not what `List.concat` expects.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to implement flatten in Scala myself, and I ran into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What's your intention with `: _*`? Remove it and your code should work.

You can actually pass List[Any] to concat, as following.

```
val list1 = List("Abby", "Jim", "Tony")
val list2 = List[Any](90,"Tom")
val ret = List.concat(list1,list2)
```

The problem of your code, I guess is with`: _*`. And another problem is `a filter (x => x.getClass == a.getClass)`, there is a small chance that an element is the same type as the container, List in your case. Is this your real intention? You want a List[Any] contains elements with type List[Any]?

Following code works, and I verified them in http://scalass.com/tryout.

```
val list = List[Any](90,"Tom")
val r = List.concat((list filter (x => x.getClass == "".getClass)))
```